# Rails Server undefined method `specs` for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-build-a-ruby-on-rails-application) guide to get started with Ruby on Rails.

I ran `ruby new <projectName>`

When I do `rails server` I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
        1: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
<projectName>/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `specs' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

No searching on SO has revealed anything so far.

I think it could be related to the build process.

When I run `bundle install`, it goes through the process before seeming to stall out

```
Fetching sassc 2.4.0
Installing sassc 2.4.0 with native extensions
Killed
```

Comment: Curiously I'm getting that too with current `rails`. Are you using Bundler 2.1.4 as well?

Comment: need more logs. post whole traceback from console

Comment: If you get "KIlled" on Linux that might be a memory issue and the OOM killer showed up. Do you have >2GB of free memory? On constrained VMs and things like a 1GB Raspberry Pi you might trip it easily.

Comment: If you don't want/need [Sass](https://sass-lang.com/ruby-sass) you can remove that from your `Gemfile` and `bundle install` again.

Comment: @tadman It looks like that was the problem. I added a swap file and the `bundle install` ran all the way through.

Answer (score 1):

I only get this if `bundle install` didn't run to completion. If you skipped that step or interrupted it the `Gemfile.lock` isn't properly generated.

The line is:

```rb
Bundler.locked_gems.specs.find { ... }
```

Where `Bundler.locked_gems` returns `nil` in the case of a missing `.lock` file.

This should be better communicated with a proper error message.

Comment: That could be it. It seems to stall out when I run `bundle install`. I updated my original post.

Comment: You need to be patient. Some of the dependencies take considerable time to compile. This is, fortunately, not something you need to do often, only when new versions of them show up and you update your `Gemfile` and/or `Gemfile.lock`.