# bundle install is hanging when installing gems

Tags: ruby, installation, rubygems

I'm trying to install [Canvas LMS](https://github.com/instructure/canvas-lms) on an Ubuntu 22.04 system.

I've tried running `bundle install` on the required gems as given by Canvas LMS.

This is the output I get:

```
Resolving dependencies...
Fetching https://github.com/wrapbook/crystalball.git
Fetching https://github.com/instructure/rspecq.git
Fetching https://github.com/twitter/thrift_client.git
Fetching https://github.com/kreynolds/cassandra-cql.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/........
Resolving dependencies...
Installing oj 3.16.3 with native extensions
Installing pg_query 5.1.0 with native extensions
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Killed
```

It gets stuck on install pg_query forever. I left it there for 2h and nothing happens.

Oddly, I did manage to install that gem manually by going `gem install pg_query` manually. It worked, and I can see the following when doing `gem info pg_query`

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

pg_query (5.1.0)
    Author: Lukas Fittl
    Homepage: https://github.com/pganalyze/pg_query
    License: BSD-3-Clause
    Installed at: /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/3.1.4/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0

    PostgreSQL query parsing and normalization library
```

I don't understand 2 things:

1. Why does it keep hanging when install pg_query?
2. Why does it even want to install pg_query? It's already there.

Comment: Why does it want to install it? Maybe your bundle path and gem path are not the same. Meaning you bundle gems for this project somewhere else (ie. `vendor/gems`) than system.

Comment: One way to try and debug it is to run with verbose and see if it's doing anything with `bundle install --verbose`

Comment: @MikeSzyndel when i run `verbose` it gives me this output: `>Installing pg_query 5.1.0 with native extensions
>Building native extensions. This could take a while...
>Killed`

Answer (score 0):

It was a memory problem. Once I created a swap file as suggested in the post below, it worked!

[Rails Server undefined method `specs` for nil:NilClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66146463/rails-server-undefined-method-specs-for-nilnilclass)